# How one can combine shift row and mix column to form a single matrix?

Tags: block-cipher, permutation, lightweight, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to combine the effect the **shift row** and **mix column** into a **single matrix**. The cipher that I am working with is **skinny64 (untweaked version)**. I know that combining the effect of these two matrices would generate a binary **64*64 matrix** but I can't seem to figure out on how this such a matrix could be constructed.

Comment: HINT: Read about [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: This gives a 16*64 (rows*col) matrix and not a 64*64 matrix.